# Different(unidentical) set of copies are returns from singleton object

Tags: java, multithreading, singleton

Please see the below Flow to understand the exact problem:

1. Tomcat Start -- Singleton Object Instantiated 1st time. Some Initial Data is set in this object from DB. e.g.data is `{XXXX, YYYY}`
2. On each request existing identical copy is returned `{XXXX, YYYY}`.
3. Data Values changed  in DB, And one flag file created from different thread after DB Data get changed. e.g. data is updated `{XXXX, YYYY, ZZZZ}`
4. File existence check during singleton object request. If file exist singleton object re-instantiated and have new values.
5. Singleton object get refreshed. `{XXXX, YYYY, ZZZZ}`
6. After the #5, Some request got the fresh copy of singleton object `{XXXX, YYYY, ZZZZ}`, However Some request Get the old copy `{XXXX, YYYY}` of singleton object.

What could be the possible reason of this discrepancy?

**Source Code**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;

import org.w3c.dom.css.Counter;


public class SingeltonObject {
      private NodesHashMap allNodes;
    private static SingeltonObject _instance = null;
    public static int counter=0;
private SingeltonObject() throws Exception{
    refresh();

}

static public SingeltonObject getInstance() throws Exception{
    if(_instance==null){
        System.out.println(" ::: First Time invoked ::: ");
        _instance = new SingeltonObject();

    }else{
        System.out.println("Thread :: "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
        System.out.println("Time :: "+System.currentTimeMillis());
        File flagFile = new File("C:/Users/rahul.singh/Desktop/Test/test.txt");
        if(flagFile.exists()){
            System.out.println("In IF"+Thread.currentThread().getName());
            _instance = new SingeltonObject();
            if(flagFile.delete()){
                System.out.println("In Delete :: "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
                System.out.println("File deleted Succesfully");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Not deleted");
            }
        }
    }


    return _instance;
}
public void refresh() throws Exception{

    allNodes = getAllNodes();

}
public static ArrayList<String> getAllNodesIDList() throws Exception {
    ArrayList<String> nodeidlist = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (String node : getInstance().allNodes.keySet()) {
        nodeidlist.add(node);
    }
    nodeidlist.trimToSize();
    return nodeidlist;
}

public static NodesHashMap getAllNodes() throws Exception {


        NodesHashMap nodesinfo = new NodesHashMap();
        ArrayList<String> nodeinfo1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        nodeinfo1.add("XN0101 MIX XN4");
        ArrayList<String> nodeinfo2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        nodeinfo2.add("XN0102 MIX XN4");
        ArrayList<String> nodeinfo3 = new ArrayList<String>();
        nodeinfo3.add("XN0103 MIX XN4");

        nodesinfo.put("XN0101", nodeinfo1);
        nodesinfo.put("XN0102", nodeinfo2);
        nodesinfo.put("XN0103", nodeinfo3);
        if(Thread.currentThread().getName().equals("T5")){
            ArrayList<String> nodeinfo4 = new ArrayList<String>();
            nodeinfo3.add("XN0104 MIX XN4");
            nodesinfo.put("XN0104", nodeinfo3);
        }

    return nodesinfo;


}

 private static class NodesHashMap extends
LinkedHashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> {
public ArrayList<String> get(String obj) throws Exception {
ArrayList<String> ret = super.get(obj);
if (ret == null) {
    SingeltonObject.getInstance().refresh();
    ret = SingeltonObject.getInstance().allNodes.get(obj);
}
return ret;
}
};
}



import java.io.File;


public class ThreadClient extends Thread{
    Thread thread1 = new Thread("T1") {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                System.out.println("T1 RUN");
                SingeltonObject.getInstance();
                SingeltonObject.getAllNodesIDList();
                System.out.println(SingeltonObject.getAllNodesIDList());

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    };
    Thread thread2 = new Thread("T2") {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                System.out.println("T2 RUN");
                SingeltonObject.getInstance();
                SingeltonObject.getAllNodesIDList();
                System.out.println(SingeltonObject.getAllNodesIDList());

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    };
    Thread thread3 = new Thread("T3") {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                System.out.println("T3 RUN");
                SingeltonObject.getInstance();
                SingeltonObject.getAllNodesIDList();
                System.out.println(SingeltonObject.getAllNodesIDList());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    };
    Thread thread4 = new Thread("T4") {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                System.out.println("T4 RUN");
                SingeltonObject.getInstance();
                SingeltonObject.getAllNodesIDList();
                System.out.println(SingeltonObject.getAllNodesIDList());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    };
Thread thread5 = new Thread("T5") {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                System.out.println("T5 RUN");
                SingeltonObject.getInstance().refresh();
                SingeltonObject.getAllNodesIDList();
                System.out.println(SingeltonObject.getAllNodesIDList());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    };

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SingeltonObject.getInstance();
        ThreadClient tclient = new ThreadClient();
        File file = new File("C:/Users/rahul.singh/Desktop/Test/test.txt");
        file.createNewFile();
        tclient.run();


    }
    public void run(){
        try {
            thread1.start();
            thread1.join();
            thread2.start();
            thread2.join();
            thread5.start();
            thread5.join();
            thread3.start();
            thread3.join();

            thread4.start();
            thread4.join();
            System.out.println("main thread finished");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }


    }
}
```

one more problem is reported which I related to singleton object not refreshed.

1. Tomcat Start -- Singleton Object Instantiated 1st time. Some Initial Data is set in this object from DB. e.g. data is `{XXXX, YYYY}`
2. On each request existing identical copy is returned `{XXXX, YYYY}`.
3. Data Values changed  in DB, And one flag file created from different thread after DB Data get changed. e.g. data is updated `{XXXX, YYYY, ZZZZ}`
4. File existence check during singleton object request. If file exist singleton object re instantiated and have new values.
5. Singleton object not get refreshed. `{XXXX, YYYY}`
6. after the #5, all request got the old copy of singleton object `{XXXX, YYYY}`

Comment: Make your getInstance() method thread safe. It might not resolve your current issue but it would save you a lot of troubles later.

Comment: Your code is not thread-safe. Not the singleton itself, and certainly not the nodes hash map (`allNodes`), which should be volatile if all threads are to see the new data. Please put some effort into learning Java concurrency when you write a program with threads.

Answer (score 0):

If you use an `enum` it will be simpler and thread safe

```
public enum SingletonObject {
    INSTANCE;

    SingletonObject() {
        System.out.println("Thread :: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        System.out.println("Time :: " + System.currentTimeMillis());
        File flagFile = new File("C:/Users/rahul.singh/Desktop/Test/test.txt");
        if (flagFile.exists()) {
            System.out.println("In IF" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            if (flagFile.delete()) {
                System.out.println("In Delete :: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                System.out.println("File deleted Succesfully");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Not deleted");
            }
        }
    }
}
```